# SQL Conditional Sum Oracle update

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I want to update `sum` for `total qty` (answer is highlighted) for `Table 1` based on Invoice_No on one click
But the condition is:

```
status = 1, then same qty else
status = 2, then qty = zero
```

[image]

Comment: Use CASE statement to have conditional SUM

Comment: @Jåcob, how to use it within 3 tables?

Comment: You should not store values computed from other tables. Will end up with data inconsistency. Either create a view, or have a _computed column_. Or, at least use triggers to ensure consistency

Comment: You have no examples in the data of `status = 2`, so your question is unclear.

Comment: @jarlh but i will trigger the sql each time when someone click on the button so it will recalculate again.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the examples, reedit the question already.

Comment: And later someone else adds some functionality somewhere else in the system, not knowing about that. That's how bugs are introduced.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use join and conditional aggregation

```
select t1.line_no,
sum(case when status=1 then Qty else 0 end ) as totalQty
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.line_no=t2.line_no
join table3 t3 on t2.line_no=t3.line_no
 and t2.part_id=t3.part_id group by t1.line_no
```

BTW it seems you are finding update so you could use below

```
merge into table1 t1 using
(
 select t2.line_no,
    sum(case when status=1 then Qty else 0 end ) as totalQty
    from table2 
    join table3 t3 on t2.line_no=t3.line_no
     and t2.part_id=t3.part_id group by t2.line_no
) a on a.line_no=t1.line_no
when matched then update set t1.totalqty=a.totalQty
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great, how about use it for update sql?

Comment: update t1 set totalqty = (select t1.line_no,
sum(case when status=1 then Qty else 0 end ) as totalQty
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.line_no=t2.line_no
join table3 t3 on t2.line_no=t3.line_no
 and t2.part_id=t3.part_id group by t1.line_no)  returns single-row subquery returns more than one row. can you advise?

Comment: @user2810084 answer edited but you should accept this answer as it already covered it your original question